# Using jQuery $.post with Phonegap (Cordova) for Android

Tags: jquery, cordova

I have a Phonegap app that needs to post data to a remote server. However, when I try to use jQuery's $.post, it will never go into the callback.

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        console.log('about to post');
        $.post('http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/index.php', function(data) {
            console.log('In callback');
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

When I run this and look in the Eclipse LogCat, I see "about to post" but I never see "In callback". I dumped this into a script tag in my PHP file on my server to make sure it is correct and sure enough, when I refresh the page I see the HTML show up in the Javascript console. I already whitelisted all domains in my config.xml file in res/xml, so I don't understand why this is not working. If anyone has any insight please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the reason you are never entering the success callback is that some kind of error is happening. Try the same request with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        console.log('about to post');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/index.php',
            data: {}, // your data (if any) should go here
            dataType: 'application/json' // or whatever you expect back
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('In callback');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

That should at least show you the error...

Comment: I agree with the above answer, in addition it maybe failing because you can't $.post to a host other than where the page was served from. This is avoided (not a problem) in phonegap, but you'll have to run in a android/ios simulator

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and was able to print out the error I was getting: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}. I tried Googling and the only results were about cross-domain scripting problems. I have tried this both on the emulator and on my phone with the same result. Maybe there's something wrong with my Phonegap config?

Comment: readyState 0 means the request was cancelled and never sent. If you think it's a CORS problem, you can confirm by running it in Chrome form the command line with the --disable-web-security option. In Chrome devtools, you can also select the option to "Log XMLHttpRequests" which will let you easily examine the request in the console

Comment: Hmm, when I run it in Chrome it works just fine. So does this mean it's a problem with my Phonegap setup?

Comment: I accepted your answer because it helped me debug the problem further. What eventually fixed it for me was REMOVING the access origin lines in my config.xml (don't ask me why). I had to comment out all access origin lines in config.xml to fix it.